# Remove trailing spaces of the code text in the editor of PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I haven't found in the editor preferences the option that allows remove trailing spaces of the code text when save a file.

Are there a plugin that will remove trailing spaces on file saving or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select All (Ctrl+A) your code
2. right click (context menu)
3. menu item "Selection"
4. submenu item "Remove Trailing Blanks"

[image]